# C++ nested class function return type and namespace

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following problem, with nested class(in this case a `struct`) namespace and return type

```
class Example
{
struct Node { /* with all the methods it needs */ }
Node * func();
}
```

now I want to put the implementation of the `func` outside the class. So what I did is:

```
Example::Node * Example::func()
{
return nullptr;
}
```

and it worked fine, until I made `example` template

```
template<typename T>
class Example {/* all the same here */}

template <typename T>
Example<T>::Node * Example<T>::func()
{
 return nullptr;
}
```

where I got many errors. Then I tried

```
 template <typename T>
Example::Node * Example<T>::func()
{
 return nullptr;
}
```

Where I get the error: "use of class template requires template argument list"

As far as I know `Example<T>::func()` is correct, because this means that function belongs to that namespace. But I'm not sure about the return type of my function. Any help?

Comment: This really answers my question, but before I asked, I didn't know I have to look for the `typename` keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are different with non-templates, they might be specialized later. In these unknown specializations, `Example<T>::Node` might be name of a static member, or the name might not exist at all.

The standard requires you to use `typename` to specify expicitly that `Example<T>::Node` is name of type, i.e. member type name of template class `Example`, not name of something else such as static member of `Example`. i.e.

```
template <typename T>
typename Example<T>::Node * Example<T>::func()
{
 return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: This really worked, but can you explain it? :)

Comment: @user5692938 I've added some explanations; for more details, see the answer of question marked duplicated.